# App symbol for PySide6 not showing in file explorer

Tags: python, qt, build, icons, pyside6

Having a PYSide6 app with icons defined:

```
    self.window.setWindowIcon(QIcon("icons/icon.ico"))
    app.setWindowIcon(QIcon("icons/icon.ico"))
```

The icons show up almost everywhere, in the top bar of the window, the taskbar in windows etc.
Just the icon in the file explorer is missing:

[image]

Any idea where to add this?

I tried adding different arguments to the build command like `--icon` which is not recognized by `pyside6-deploy` and also adding an entry to the `pysidedeply.spec` didn't change anything.

Comment: pyside6-deploy is based on Nuitka, you should look for command line options in its documentation.

Comment: Use the ```nuitka``` parameter of the pyside6-deploy spec file and the ```--windows-icon-from-ico``` option of Nuitka. See [Nuitka User Manual - Tweaks - Icons](https://nuitka.net/doc/user-manual.html#icons).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, it lead me to the right answer:

I used in the `pysidedeploy.spec` file the following arguments:

```
[nuitka]
extra_args = --quiet --noinclude-qt-translations=True --windows-icon-from-ico=icons/icon.ico
```